# Check if folder exists in a webserver using python and http functions

Tags: python, http, file-exists

Is there a way to check if a folder exists on a web server with Python? (something like "os.path.isdir" but reading HTTP responses as "HTTP/404" if not found)

Comment: There's no such thing as a folder over HTTP. A form of this (collections) were added in the WebDAV extension. Did you mean this? Without webdav, no folders though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a server is serving a file by requesting it in urllib and seeing if it was successfull with a 200 error or unsuccessful.

I think it's difficult to see what is a directory and what isn't.  What is a directory though? With modern web frameworks people can route urls however they want.  Are you defining a a directory as anything that has a webpage underneath of it even though it might not be hierarchical order on the filesystem?

```
import urllib

f = urllib.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822223/check-if-folder-exists-in-a-webserver-using-python-and-http-functions/')
if f.code == 200:
  #success
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822223/check-if-folder-exists-in-a-webserver-using-python-and-http-functions')

if r:
  print "Exists"
else:
  print "Doesn't exist"
```